# In iOS is there a way to simulate a Geographical region crossing when app is installed while within location

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

In my app, I am using the [Boundary-Crossing Events for a Geographical Region](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) to determine if a user has visited a location. This is working as expected when users have installed the app prior to visiting the location, however some users will be installing the app while they are at the event, and therefore are already within the location when the event is installed and so iOS does not treat this as a boundary crossing.

Is there a way to force iOS to trigger the locationManager:didEnterRegion method if the startMonitoringForRegion method is called while the device is currently within the region to monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS7, you can use [requestStateForRegion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestStateForRegion:) method of the CLLocationManager class to check whether the user is already inside a fence.

You need to implement below delegate method to receive the event.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
}
```

Thanks to this article for the answer (as well as a solution for iOS version < 7: http://hayageek.com/ios-geofencing-api/